# How xUnit initialize data not related to theory\fact being run?

Tags: c#, xunit.net

I would like to know if xUnit, similar to nUnit, generates test data even when test that is being run do not require it ? In nUnit when I have two test classes with tests:

```
public class Test1
{
    public void Test()
    {
        ...do smth
    }
}
public class Test2
{
    [TestCaseSource(source)]
    public void Test(string name)
    {
        ...do testing using name parameter
    }
}
```

When I run test from class Test1, it initialize test data I pass to test in class test2(they have open issue for fixing it https://github.com/nunit/nunit-console/issues/438).

Is it similar with xUnit ?

Comment: I've stared at this and cant figure out what you're asking. Can you add examples please and/or format the text

Comment: @RubenBartelink hi, sorry it took so long to answer but I did some formatting. I hope it will help understanding my question. Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not any less confused - xUnit runs Test Classes in random order (normally in parallel). It also runs Test Methods within a Test Class in random order. This is to shake out order dependencies in your logic, which is never a good thing. In general you'll find that xUnit is never more tolerant than NUnit. Note your code is still not a fully self-contained example of what you're trying to do - I'm guessing and reading in between the lines